# install llvm binaries without version number

Tags: llvm

When I install llvm using command
`bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"`

The binaries that get installed looks like following

[image: snapshot of installed binaries]

All the binaries have version number. For e.g. llvm-objdump-15.

But the tools I use are looking for llvm-objdump, while installer installed it as llvm-objdump-15. I can create a symbolic link with name llvm-obdump, but I want to know how to install it correctly and not have version numbers in all these binaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using apt-get install

```
sudo apt-get install clang-format clang-tidy clang-tools clang clangd libc++-dev libc++1 libc++abi-dev libc++abi1 libclang-dev libclang1 liblldb-dev libllvm-ocaml-dev libomp-dev libomp5 lld lldb llvm-dev llvm-runtime llvm python3-clang
```

It did install an older version, but it was fine for my needs

Answer (score 0):

The names without version numbers are controlled by the `llvm-defaults` package on your distribution. It picks a specific version to make the default, and only that one has un-versioned symlinks installed into the system `PATH`.

As a consequence, on Debian based systems only one version (controlled by the distro) is going to be available there and it may not be the one from `https://apt.llvm.org/`. On these systems, the recommended way to use a specific version is to add the suffix.

If you can't do that, you should install the distro-provided version using the normal process rather than the versions on `https://apt.llvm.org/`.

To read more details about how all of this works, you can check out the documentation for the `llvm-defaults` package set here: https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-llvm-team/llvm-defaults/-/blob/experimental/debian/README.Debian